# Деструктуризации посчитать сумму по условию

Tags: javascript

Ребята подскажите как посчитать сумму массива с помощью деструктиризации

```js
при условии сумма числе больше 0
const arr=[-34, 4,23]
```

Comment: О_о деструктуризация вообще не для этого предназначена. А элементов всегда три?)

Comment: посчитай сумму с помощью `reduce`

Comment: мы с вами что кофе пили что вы мне тыкаете. проявляете уважения у девелоперам)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const arr = [-34, 4,23];
let [a, b, c] = arr;
let sum = a + b + c;
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут деструктуризации не нужна
Это не с помощью деструктуризации, но думаю это вам поможет как неплохое решение

```js
arr.reduce((acc, e) => acc + e)
```